# Using flexbox to make a navbar with 3 divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nav

I am trying to make a navigation bar that has three `<div>` elements, using flexbox layout; the desired look would have content on the far left, center, and far right. I just can't get them to separate from each other.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.left-navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.middle-navbar ul {
  align-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 40px;
}

.right-navbar {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="left-navbar">
      <h1>Ben Resume</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right-navbar">
      <button type="button" name="Download CV">Download CV</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've also deleted unnecessary codes

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around; /*or space-between*/
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.links {
  align-content: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.links a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="left-navbar">
    <h1>Ben Resume</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#">Introduction</a>
    <a href="#">About Me</a>
    <a href="#">Reviews</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <button type="button" name="Download CV">Download CV</button>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `justify-content: space-between;` to your `.nabvar-wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

You must give the a width to .navbar-wrapper, and use justify-content: space-between for example`

```
.navbar-wrapper{
width:100%;
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
```

`

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two solutions when using `flex`:

Using **space-between** (from a parent perspective)

```css
/* QuickReset */ *, ::after, ::before { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div>ONE</div>
  <div>TWO</div>
  <div>THREE</div>
</div>
```

or using **margin auto** (from a child perspective)

```css
/* QuickReset */ *, ::after, ::before { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.row-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div>ONE</div>
  <div class="row-center">TWO</div>
  <div>THREE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just finished the CSS portion of Angela Yu's course on Udemy so I am still learning how to actually apply CSS. Would you mind explaining to me the "QuickReset" line in both solutions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @TJCullen the `*` *global (universal) selector* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors is there to target every element on the page. Find out more about *CSS Resets* here: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/  I always use nowadays this simple one to remove unwanted Vendor User Agent Stylesheets. For example I don't want the default margins to the body element, etc. Regargin box-sizing and other CSS, HTML, JS properties, methods etc, always refer to the amazing MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing